# How to solve the problem with MySQL Workbench on Mac

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to save configuration file onMySQL Workbench on Mac, but I have the following error

```
parameter "filename" must be an absolute path: ~/sandboxes/msb_|Enter version here|/my.sandbox.cnf
```

Could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try using the full path instead of the name.
For example, /home/filename